# Altered Carbon Season 2 and the DHF in Poe's memory

Tags: altered-carbon

The DHF saved in Poe's memory at the very end of the second season of the Netflix show 'Altered Carbon' is probably the most recent version of Takeshi Kovacs. I guess that that was to prepare season 3 which will be never made.

My question is: **When in season 2 was this DHF backed up in Poe's memory? Is there a scene showing that?**

I've just started to read the first volume of the novel (in French).

Comment: I don't think the novel will answer any questions like this, as the series started deviating pretty heavily from the novels at latest half-way through season 1.

Comment: DHF? Not having seen the second season yet, what is a DHF?

Comment: @NJohnny   After Wikipedia, Digital Human Freight. In French, THD, HD for Humain Digitalisé, and I don't know for the T. It's where the memory and the personality are saved. It's not clear that it is the mind or the soul because a sleeve (enveloppe in French) does not behave like a human body; it seems that when the stack containing the DHF is removed from a sleeve, the sleeve dies, at least in the show, I don't know in the book. We have no stack in the neck and we are alive :-).